# How to bind the slider with the arrow key inputs?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, slider, arrow-keys

I have a slider control and all I wanted is to move the slider thumb with the arrow key inputs. Right now, I could see it moves with mouse inputs and PageUp/PageDown keys. But nothing happens with the arrow keys. How can I change this behaviour in xaml?

Any help anybody could produce would highly appreciated.

Thanks

Ratheesh

Comment: debugged the application and checked the code, public int MySpeed {get{return this.speed;}set{this.speed = value;} when pageUp/Down keys are pressed, the value is incremented/decremented and this.speed is set, but for arrow keys, it is not changed and the same value is set. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Please check the xaml code <Slider IsEnabled="True" TabIndex="3" Minimum="0" Maximum="150" Value="{Binding MySpeed}" MinWidth="150"}"/>

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The default SmallChange value for a RangeBase is 0.1. Since you are bound to an integer property I'm guessing that is getting rounded/truncated. Try setting the SmallChange to 1 and the LargeChange to something else (e.g. 10).

Comment: Thanks man.. thanks for the reply.. U say this would work for the arrow keys? but how to change the default Smallchange value?

Comment: Thanks AndrewS, it worked for me. I have given SmallChange="1" to the slider control and was able to move the slider thumb by the left/right arrow keys. Thanks man..